# Can't Find a way to ignore bin dir contents and keep the bin dir

Tags: git, ignore

In my app I have some directories that I want git to ignore, but I want the directories themselves to remain in the repository. A complication is that these directories are sometimes deleted automatically by build tools. Therefore putting a .gitignore inside the directory telling it to ignore everything but itself (the solution suggested in many posts) will not work. The .gitignore file will be deleted automatically at times.

So I created a .gitignore entry in the top level directory of my project, telling it to ignore contents of the subdirectory `target` like this.

`**/target/*`

That works exactly as I want it to. Once I committed the `target` dir with something in it and pushed it to the remote, subsequent changes to the contents of `target` are ignored, and `target` is never removed from the remote repo.

The problem is that when I do this with `bin` it doesn't work. When I enter `git add /path/to/bin` (when `bin` is not empty) it doesn't add it, although I have no `.gitigore` file anywhere telling git to ignore it. I can get it to add it by `git add --force bin` but then it adds everything, and tracks subsequent changes to everything in `bin`.

It's strange that this works for `target` but not for `bin`. It seems like git is hard-coded to ignore `bin dirs`, even when I don't have a `.gitignore` entry telling it to do so.

Comment: Is this particular `bin` directory already committed to the repository?  This would explain why adding it to `.gitignore` is not working.  There is nothing special about `bin` AFAIK.

Comment: I don't think it's already committed. That's actually the behavior I'm desiring. Other devs are going to pull the code and run a maven build on it, and the bin and target dirs need to be there for the maven build. I push to the remote after adding bin/.gitkeep, and I see it there via the web interface. When that file is deleted during a local build, git marks it as changed, and if I add, commit, and push, the bin dir is gone also from the remote. At that point, there are other contents in bin, but since .gitkeep is the file I added, removing it results in the entire bin dir being gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can not add a empty folder to git even by `git by git add --force bin`.

Essentially, git manage files by pathname, one node for one file, instead of folder.

You must put a .gitkeep file in bin folder and add it by `git add bin/.gitkeep`,
at the same time, write ignore rules as following to ignore files in bin folder, instead of whole folder.

```
bin/*  
!.gitkeep
```

Comment: As I mentioned, the challenge I have is that I can't depend on keeping the .gitkeep file in bin/. It's an eclipse project, and when I clean the project, it deletes the .gitkeep file. I can't find a way to not do that. Thus after a clean, the bin/ dir is no longer in the remote repo. The class files are, but they're being ignored as desired. I have the same problem with target dirs deleted by maven clean, but this arrangement works for those. Maybe the problem is that eclipse adds a /bin/ entry in .gitigore when I build. There is no way to override that for just one project, however.